# CSS class name with id after it?

Tags: php, html, css

I have this:

```
<div class="likebutton" numberlikes$post="$totallikes">
```

$post is an id number that php sends.

my problem here is how can CSS understant that I want numberlikes with any number after it, eg:
numberlikes63463436
numberlikes548548
...

my css:

```
.likebutton:before{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 content: attr(numberlikes);
 background:blue;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

how can I tell css that numberlikes will have a random number after it?
I try put =^id after numberlikes but it is not working...

```
content: attr(numberlikes=^id);
```

thank you!

Comment: Why do you need `$post` in the attribute? You shouldn't be creating custom attributes in the first place.

Comment: that is because in the same page I have many like buttons with different ids, when click in a button it calls an ajax action that incrise numberlikes, and ajax need to know with one numberlike will be incrised, so that is why i need this $post

Comment: Put the number in the `id`, not in `numberlikes`.

Comment: you could make a custom attribute like data-numberslike="1231", and then i am sure you will easy manage to both apply the css and manage your custom actions

Comment: custom attributes are not valid. Please consider to create an id-attribute and input it there. But be informed that these custom attributes working well but they are not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `$post` in the attribute name, put it in the `id` attribute.

```css
.likebutton:before{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 content: attr(data-numberlikes);
 background:blue;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="likebutton" id="likebutton$post" data-numberlikes="$totallikes">
```

Comment: thank you! I will try it now.. in fact it should work!!